# Data wont submit from PDO

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and trying out PDO instead of mysqli. However, I cannot get the values for firstname and lastname into the sql database when I click submit. What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php 

$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxx';
$db = 'xxxxxx';

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>

<html>
<form name="Contact form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> 
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit this!" name="submit">
</form>
</html>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO names (fname,lname) VALUES (:$_POST[firstname],:$_POST[lastname])");

}

?>

<?php $con = null; ?>
```

Comment: Assuming I'm reading your php correctly.. since you aren't using parameterized values, your sql is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: `:$_POST[firstname]` looks strange to me.  The colon...is it suppose to be there.  I always parametrize my values.

Comment: @Kubee: no, it isn't supposed to be there. The "correct" (yet from a security standpoint, horrible) way to write it would be to omit the colon.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on this line:

```
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO names (fname,lname) VALUES (:$_POST[firstname],:$_POST[lastname])");
```

The colons shouldn't be there and the inserted values should be quoted. The easiest (also most secure and faster) way to achieve that is to use a prepared query:

```
$statement = $con->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO names (fname,lname) 
     VALUES (:firstname,:lastname)');
$result = $statement->exec(array(
    'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'], 
    'lastname' => $_POST['lastname']));
```

Also please read more about SQL injection. Your original code has a security flaw. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1):

You ought to split the `->query()` it into a [`->prepare`](http://php.net/pdostatement.prepare) and [`->execute`](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute) call to actually utilize prepared statements / bound parameters:

```
 $st = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO names (fname,lname) VALUES (:first, :last)");
 $result = $st->execute(array("first"=>$_POST["firstname"], "last"=>$_POST["lastname"]));
```

If you want to use `->query()` then you need to use [`$con->quote()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.quote) on the various string variables before concatenating it into the query.